# Issue running yb-sample-apps benchmark in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Can someone help me with below issue.

```
java -jar yb-sample-apps.jar --workload SqlInserts  --nodes 192.168.33.131:9042
1 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.Main  - Starting sample app...
57 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Using a randomly generated UUID : 3c3d2620-2ddb-4d17-afb5-aca555c5d45f
68 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - App: SqlInserts
68 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Run time (seconds): -1
68 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Adding node: 192.168.33.131:9042
68 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Num reader threads: 2, num writer threads: 2
68 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Num unique keys to insert: 2000000
68 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Num keys to update: 0
68 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Num keys to read: 1500000
68 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Value size: 0
68 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Restrict values to ASCII strings: false
68 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Perform sanity check at end of app run: false
68 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Table TTL (secs): -1
68 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Local reads: false
69 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.common.CmdLineOpts  - Read only load: false
235808 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.apps.AppBase  - Going to retrieve connection again: An error occurred while setting up the SSL connection.
535799 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.apps.AppBase  - Going to retrieve connection again: An error occurred while setting up the SSL connection.
835799 [main] INFO com.yugabyte.sample.apps.AppBase  - Going to retrieve connection again: An error occurred while setting up the SSL connection.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `SqlInserts` workload you have to use `--nodes 192.168.33.131:5433` for cassandra workload you need to pass `9042` port. As it's a single node, if you haven't enabled `ssl_key` then for cassandra workload e.g.

```bash
java -jar yb-sample-apps.jar --workload CassandraKeyValue --nodes 192.168.33.131:9042 --username cassandra --password cassandra  and sql workload java -jar yb-sample-apps.jar --workloaSqlDataLoad --nodes 192.168.33.131:5433 --username yugabyte --password yugabyte
```

Parameters for YSQL API:

```
java -jar yb-sample-apps.jar --workload <workload app name> --nodes <HOSTNAME>:5433 --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD> --ssl_key <CERT_PATH>
```

Parameters for YCQL API:

```
java -jar yb-sample-apps.jar --workload <workload app name> --nodes <HOSTNAME>:9042 --username <USERNAME> --password <PASSWORD> --ssl_key <CERT_PATH>
```